# What's the definition of being dense in a subset of a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be our topological space, and $A\subset C \subset X$.

If $A$ is dense in $X$, then we would have that $\bar A = X$.

What does it mean to say $A$ is dense in $C$?

Is it $\bar A \cap C = C$, or $\bar A = C$?

Comment: Let me answer with another question: Is "$\bar{A}$" the closure of $A$ in $X$, or the closure of $A$ in $C$ (where $C$ is a subspace of $X$)?

Comment: Follow-up comment: Consider your question in the context of $A = \{q\in\mathbb{Q}\ |\ 0<q<1\}$, $C = (0,1)$, and $X = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Neal thanks for the comments. I'm using the closure of A in X. I get your point now. ;)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3231056/is-denseness-a-antisymmetric-relation/3231967#3231967).

Comment: A useful tool is that if $A\subset X$ and $A$ is dense in $X$ then $A\cap U$ is dense in $U$ for every open $U\subset X.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is $\overline{A}^{(C)}=C$, where the closure is taken in the subspace $C$.

But it is well known that $\overline{A}^{(C)}=\overline{A} \cap C$ where the right hand closure is taken in $X$. And so it is equivalent too $C \subseteq \overline{A}$.

Comment: Henno, thanks for your answer. ;)

Comment: Henno, by the way, do we also have $int_C(A)=int(A)\cap C$ and $\partial_C(A) = (\partial A )\cap C$?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. No to interior as witnessed by the rationals inside the reals, e.g. So boundary also fails.